# Mistakenly deleted codedeploy-agent

Tags: amazon-web-services

I mistakenly deleted codedeploy-agent folder now I cannot run install or codedeploy erase,

```
Stop codedeploy-agent in preun hook if this is an erase.
Stopping codedeploy-agent:/etc/init.d/codedeploy-agent: line 45: cd: /opt/codedeploy-agent/: No such file or directory
Unable to stop the running codedeploy-agent
Canceling uninstall of the agent..
error: %preun(codedeploy-agent-1.3.2-1902.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package codedeploy-agent-1.3.2-1902.noarch
  Verifying  : codedeploy-agent-1.3.2-1902.noarch                                                                   1/1

Failed:
  codedeploy-agent.noarch 0:1.3.2-1902
```

how do I reinstall codedeploy-agent or erase it now?
I've tried `sudo ./install auto`

```
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.233152 #3540]  INFO -- : Starting Ruby version check.
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.233406 #3540]  INFO -- : Starting update check.
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.233511 #3540]  INFO -- : Attempting to automatically detect supported package manager type for system...
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.241988 #3540]  INFO -- : Checking AWS_REGION environment variable for region information...
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.242075 #3540]  INFO -- : Checking EC2 metadata service for region information...
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.266428 #3540]  INFO -- : Checking AWS_DOMAIN environment variable for domain information...
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.266506 #3540]  INFO -- : Checking EC2 metadata service for domain information...
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.273211 #3540]  INFO -- : Downloading version file from bucket aws-codedeploy-us-east-1 and key latest/LATEST_VERSION...
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.273619 #3540]  INFO -- : Endpoint: https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/LATEST_VERSION
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.351061 #3540]  INFO -- : Running version matches target version, skipping install
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.351223 #3540]  INFO -- : Update check complete.
I, [2022-08-19T16:28:49.351255 #3540]  INFO -- : Stopping updater.
```

it doesn't install

Comment: You've made statements, but what's your actual question?

Comment: How can I erase or re install code deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the error, because I deleted the codedeploy-agent folder in /opt, install and erase command returned errors, because /etc/init.d was making reference to the files in an attempt to install or erase. So I deleted the codedeploy-agent folder in /etc/init.d by running

"cd /etc/init.d
sudo rm -r codedeploy-agent"

then "cd" to return to starting directory, then ran

sudo yum erase codedeploy-agent
sudo ./install auto

Please note before running sudo ./install auto, you must have ran

"sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y install ruby
sudo yum -y install wget
cd /home/ec2-user
wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
sudo chmod +x ./install"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu, check the version you're running by:

```
lsb_release -a
```

If your Ubuntu server version is >= 16.04 just enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install ruby-full

sudo apt install wget
```

then

```
cd /home/ubuntu

wget https://bucket-name.s3.region-identifier.amazonaws.com/latest/install

sudo ./install auto
```

Now check if the service is running by:

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

If you're not using Ubuntu or your version is lower than the one I mentioned, check AWS official tutorial by [clicking here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-cli.html).

If you deleted the folder because of the copies Codedeploy-agent generates each deployment process which can make your disk out of space, next time, just delete the folders inside deployment-root and set Codedeploy's max_revision. [See more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-agent-configuration.html).

Comment: I already ran sudo ./install auto, and posted the error above

Comment: So just run "sudo dpkg --purge codedeploy-agent" for uninstalling it then run the install command again

Comment: dpkg command not found

Comment: Are you using Linux or what? If it is Linux so run "sudo yum erase codedeploy-agent". AWS' tutorial for unninstaling Codedeploy Agent: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-uninstall.html

Comment: already tried that as indicated in the post